# Set a variable select matching rows using an inner join with case statement t-sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, inner-join, case-statement

I am trying to get matching rows from two tables using an inner join and if they all match then set to `0` else set to `1`. Finally, I want to set that `1` or `0` into a variable `@duplicate_counts`.

Sample Data `ClaimsTable`, (Both, `ClaimsTable` and `#tempTable` have identical columns)

```
   Time             Terminal_ID   Count
------------------------------------
2017-10-19 06:03:00     1         5
2017-10-19 06:04:00     1         2
2017-10-19 06:05:00     1         2
2017-10-19 06:06:00     1         2
2017-10-19 06:03:00     9         2
2017-10-19 06:04:00     9         3
2017-10-19 06:05:00     9         2
2017-10-19 06:06:00     9         3
2017-10-19 06:06:00     9         3
```

`#tempTable`,

```
 Time             Terminal_ID   Count
 ------------------------------------
 2017-10-19 06:03:00        1         5
 2017-10-19 06:04:00        1         2
 2017-10-19 06:05:00        1         2
 2017-10-19 06:06:00        1         2
 2017-10-19 06:03:00        9         2
 2017-10-19 06:04:00        9         3
 2017-10-19 06:05:00        9         2
 2017-10-19 06:06:00        9         3
```

Now, I want to check the matching rows of both tables using `innerjoin`. If they have matching rows, I want to set the variable `@duplicate_counts` to `0` and if they don't I want to set `@duplicate_counts` to `1`. In this case, `ClaimsTables`'s last record is a duplicate.

All I am doing is a check to see if there is any to make sure I don't have any duplicates.

I tried CASE Statement like this,

```
declare @duplicate_counts int
    set @duplicate_counts =(select 
    CASE WHEN
    (
        select count(*) 
        from ClaimsTable
        inner join #temptable
            on #temptable.[time] = ClaimsTable.[time] 
            and #temptable.terminal_id = ClaimsTable. terminal_id
    )
    THEN 0
    ELSE 1
END
select @duplicate_counts
```

This, statement gave me an error:

> An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a
>   condition is expected, near 'then'.

After this, I will do an `if` statement like this,

```
if @duplicate_counts = 1 
            begin
            --insert duplicates into bin table
            insert into BinTable
            ...
```

This way, the last record of the `ClaimsTable` will be inserted to `BinTable`.

How can I set to 0 if they match else 1 in case statement?

Comment: I'm confused.  Do you want a count or a row-by-row flag?  Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I am checking two tables if they have any matching values. So, it is a row-by-row flag. I will post sample data and output I want!

Comment: The error message is pretty clear I think... your SELECT COUNT(*) statement in the case returns a number, not a true/false. What is it you really want to do?

Comment: You might want to step back here and ask what you are trying to accomplish.  Your thought here is very linear and that doesn't work well in SQL.  Select yadda from table group by yadda having count(1) > 1 will give all values for yadda that have more than one instance in your table (duplicate).  Use an update statement with that to mass update, don't go 1 row at a time in variables.  It looks like this problem has come up because of the way you are logically approaching your scripting a long time prior to this error.

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @duplicate_counts int 
IF
    (
        select count(*) 
        from ClaimsTable
        inner join #temptable
            on #temptable.[time] = ClaimsTable.[time] 
            and #temptable.terminal_id = ClaimsTable. terminal_id
    ) = (select count(*) from #temptable) 
    set @duplicate_counts = 0
 ELSE 
    set @duplicate_counts = 1

select @duplicate_counts
```

Comment: you're missing a parenthesis after `(select count(*) FROM #temptable)..`

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure what you are going for here. I would simply get the count and then insert the duplicates separately, but this would do it the way you are looking for:

```
declare @duplicate_counts int
set @duplicate_counts = (
SELECT SELECT COUNT(0) - SUM( CASE WHEN #temptable.terminal_id IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM ClaimsTable LEFT OUTER JOIN #temptable 
ON #temptable.[time] = ClaimsTable.[time] 
AND ClaimsTable.terminal_id = #temptable.terminal_id
)
select @duplicate_counts
```